# How can I determine how an NHibernate entity key is generated at execution time?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I have adapted the Identity Entity Framework project to an NHibernate version. Now I have an `ApplicationUser` class like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
{
    // TODO Auto determine if Id must be generated here or at DB.
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, TKey> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

In my current project, we use `int` keys for everything, backed by `Identity` fields in the database. In this scenario, I would prefer the method generated a negative int temporary id, instead of using `manager.CreateIdentityAsync`, but if I use Identity as it is normally used, and `typeof(TKey)` is `string`, I'd like this method to work normally.

But, NB, I'm not concerned with the type of the id, but whether I must generate it in my app, or whether the DB will generate it for me, and that is what I want to find out at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need can get the identifier generator using the `SessionFactory`:

```
var generator = ((ISessionFactoryImplementor)Session.SessionFactory)
    .GetIdentifierGenerator(typeof(TEntity).FullName);

if (generator is Assigned)
{
    // Generate the identifier
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I only started with NHibernate two weeks ago, and found it clumsy compared to EF 6, but each time I learn something like this, I love it even more. Thanks.